# rails - instance model include module on variable condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, module

I need to know if I can include a module to an instantiated model.

What works today :

**in the controller**

```
@m = MyModel.create(params)
```

**in the model**

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_save :set_include

   def set_include
     if bool
       self.class.send(:include, Module1)
     else
       self.class.send(:include, Module2)
     end
   end

end
```

and this works, but I'm afraid that `self.class` actually include the module for the class model an not the **instantiated model**

In this case, this will work.
The module methods are call after the object is saved.

But in many case, the controller will call some modules methods.

**I thought of**  called the method `set_include` (up there) in a `before_action` of the controller.
But I really thinks that is not a good idea...

Any idea how I can really do that with in a good way ?

thanks !

Comment: does not make a lot of sense imo, just include both modules and use its' methods

Comment: the both modules as the same method names, that's why. Caused of old code that can't really be easily refactored

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your direct question is **no**. Your code only appears to be working and is actually **not** modifying instance of a class, but the **class itself**. So all instances of it will be getting this "benefit". Probably not what you wanted. Let me demonstrate with simple ruby example: https://repl.it/BnLO

What you can do instead is use [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-extend) with instance like: https://repl.it/BnLO/2

Applied to your code it would be:

```
class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save :set_include

   def set_include
     if bool
       extend(Module1)
     else
       extend(Module2)
     end
   end
end
```

Also, `self` is not necessary. https://repl.it/BnLO/3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instance class (a.k.a eigenklass):

```
def set_include
  singleton_class.instance_eval do
    include bool ? Module1 : Module2
  end
end
```

However the fact that you want to do this is suspicious and might lead to a disaster. So the question is: what are you really trying to achieve here - there surely is the better way of doing so.

Comment: as I said, both modules as the same method names, because of old code that can't really be easily refactored, and to avoid if and else in many places.
But If it can't be achieved, I'll find an other way

Comment: It can be achieved with code above, but it will most likely cause you a lot of headache in the future.